# bottle framework with multiple files

Tags: python, frameworks, bottle

I've read the Bottle Documentation but I can't find the example of how to use Bottle with multiple files. Below is the way I did and it's working but I'm not sure whether this is the proper way to go (I saw `merge()` and `mount()` in API but not sure if they are related to this). Please give me the comments.

1. all.py  (This is the main file for running)

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/python
   from bottle import route, run

   import hello1
   import hello2    # if I have 10 files, it will be 10 imports

   run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
   ```
2. hello1.py

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/python
   from bottle import route, run

   @route('/hello1')
   def hello1():
       return "Hello world no.1"
   ```
3. hello2.py

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/python
   from bottle import route, run

   @route('/hello2')
   def hello2():
       return "Hello world no.2"
   ```

Answer (score 14):

I've wanted to use a single bottle server to serve a suite of micro-applications and for a decent separation of concerns, have wanted to do what you've been looking for.

Here's how I resolved my task:

**rootApp.py** (Your main file)

```
from bottle import Bottle
from clientApp import clientApp

rootApp = Bottle()
@rootApp.route('/')
def rootIndex():
    return 'Application Suite Home Page'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rootApp.merge(clientApp)
    rootApp.run(debug=True)
```

**clientApp.py** (The new app needing to be merged into the suite)

```
from bottle import Bottle

clientApp = Bottle()

@clientApp.route('/clientApp')
def clientAppIndex():
    return 'Client App HomePage'
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it seems to work without complaints and saves the hassle of having to [share ports between applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044939/python-bottle-can-run-two-programs-on-the-same-address-and-port-on-windows) that could otherwise have mutual knowledge. The approach really stems out of a design preference but I'd be grateful if someone could demonstrate how/if the AppStack could be used to get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

If you split your code into 10 Python modules, you’re going to do 10 imports. You can iterate with `__import__`:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    __import__('hello%d' % i)
```

but this doesn’t strike me as a good idea. Why would you *need* 10 modules with a micro-framework?

Comment: I guess it shouldnt matter if its a micro-framework. If I am creating a web API and I have say 20 tables in my DB and each table kind of maps to one resource and I want to keep the request handlers and associated ORM for each table in independent files, wont it be the right way to do it? I am relative new to both python and bottle so correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the BEST way, but indeed **mount()** [might be used](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html) and looks good for me (tested with python 3.6 + Bottle 0.12.13).

**First** of all, building one of your "sub apps" in a `app1.py` file:

```
from bottle import Bottle

server1 = Bottle()
@server1.route('/')
def root():
    return 'Hello from sub app 1'
```

**Then** you use it in your main app:

```
from bottle import Bottle
from app1 import server1 

mainApp = Bottle()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainApp.mount('/appli1', server1)
    mainApp.run()
```

**Lets go:**

Hit your server address: http://myServer/appli1

Let me know if you need a fully functional example.

Comment: This appears to be the "correct" way according to the Bottle documentation: https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#default-app

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to have one module per view? The views are usually grouped in some logical manner, e.g.:

- `/`, `/post/:id`, `/tags`/, `/tag/:tag` in `blog.py`,
- `/admin`, `/admin/newpost`, `/admin/editpost/:id` in `admin.py`,
- and so forth.

You should also read the chapter [Becoming Big](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/) from the Flask documentation. For a medium-sized app, you'll probably want to create a package with a layout similar to this:

```
/yourapplication
    /runserver.py
    /yourapplication
        /__init__.py
        /views.py
        /static
            /style.css
        /templates
            layout.html
            index.html
            login.html
```

For even larger apps, split views into a sub-package.